# How to alter a .NET DateTimePicker control to allow enter null values?

Tags: .net, datetimepicker, null

What's the easiest and most robust way of altering the .NET DateTimePicker control, to allow users to enter `null` values?

Comment: Another option is to use a MaskedTextBox with a mask of `00/00/0000`.  This allows somewhat intuitive data entry and probably the most intuitive UX for backing out a date field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an approach from this CodeProject article on creating a [Nullable DateTimePicker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/Nullable_DateTimePicker.aspx).

> I have overridden the `Value` property to accept `Null` value as `DateTime.MinValue`, while maintaining the validation of `MinValue` and `MaxValue` of the standard control.

Here's a version of the custom class component from the article

```cs
public class NullableDateTimePicker : System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
{
    private DateTimePickerFormat originalFormat = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    private string originalCustomFormat;
    private bool isNull;

    public new DateTime Value
    {
        get => isNull ? DateTime.MinValue : base.Value;
        set
        {
            // incoming value is set to min date
            if (value == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                // if set to min and not previously null, preserve original formatting
                if (!isNull)
                {
                    originalFormat = this.Format;
                    originalCustomFormat = this.CustomFormat;
                    isNull = true;
                }

                this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                this.CustomFormat = " ";
            }
            else // incoming value is real date
            {
                // if set to real date and previously null, restore original formatting
                if (isNull)
                {
                    this.Format = originalFormat;
                    this.CustomFormat = originalCustomFormat;
                    isNull = false;
                }

                base.Value = value;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCloseUp(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        // on keyboard close, restore format
        if (Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None)
        {
            if (isNull)
            {
                this.Format = originalFormat;
                this.CustomFormat = originalCustomFormat;
                isNull = false;
            }
        }
        base.OnCloseUp(eventargs);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        // on delete key press, set to min value (null)
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
        {
            this.Value = DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes Mr Grazoli's NullableDateTimePicker does do the job although I think that someone should review it and try and get rid of those ugly WndProc calls

Comment: The other thing about the code is that it didn't seem to do what it was supposed to do. I don't know, maybe I was doing something wrong. Don't have a lot of time to spend messing around with it. Using the DTPs ShowCheckBox idea seems more promising really.

Comment: While the solution allows the user to clear out a date, you can no longer set focus to the control or use the keyboard to re-enter a non null date. One step fwd, two back.

Answer (score 47):

You don't need to modify it to do this.

The `DateTimePicker` in .net actually has a checkbox built-in.

Set the `ShowCheckBox` property to `true`.

Then you can use the `Checked` property to see if the user has entered a value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.showcheckbox(VS.80).aspx

Comment: The checkbox implementation is all kinds of fail though. Doesn't trigger events properly.

Answer (score 4):

Placing an additional checkbox labeled something like "enable notification" that enables / disables the DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 2):

Tri's solution did not quite cut it for me and so thought Mr. Grazioli and he did something about it: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c9645

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ShowCheckBox` property to `true`.

Then you can use the Checked property as follows:

```cs
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTimePicker thisDateTimePicker = (DateTimePicker)sender;
    if (thisDateTimePicker.Checked == false)
    {
        thisDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = @" "; //space
        thisDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    }
    else
    {
        thisDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    }
}
```

Comment: from all proposed solutions this was the easiest, shortest and ui friendly

Answer (score 0):

I posted my long way around solution, which has some findings in the code comments about the peculiar issues with this control:

[DateTime Picker null value](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/f1f8cc0a-0ac9-4a3e-9ba4-9af495e8ff58/)