# How can I make a DateTimePicker display an empty string?

Tags: .net, winforms, datetimepicker

I would like to be able to display a `DateTimePicker` that has a default value of nothing, i.e. no date.

For example, I have a start date `dtTaskStart` and an end date `dtTaskEnd` for a task, but the end date is not known, and not populated initially.

I have specified a custom format of `yyyy-MM-dd` for both controls.

Setting the value to `null`, or an empty string at runtime causes an error, so how can I accomplish this?

I have considered using a checkbox to control the enabling of this field, but there is still the issue of displaying an initial value..

*Edit:*
Arguably a duplicate of the question [DateTimePicker Null Value (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284364/datetimepicker-null-value-net), but the solution I found for my problem is not a solution for that question, so I think it should remain here for others to find..

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTimePicker Null Value (.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284364/datetimepicker-null-value-net)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Obfuscating the value by using the `CustomFormat` property, using checkbox `cbEnableEndDate` as the flag to indicate whether other code should ignore the value:

```vb
If dateTaskEnd > Date.FromOADate(0) Then
    dtTaskEnd.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    dtTaskEnd.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dtTaskEnd.Value = dateTaskEnd 
    dtTaskEnd.Enabled = True
    cbEnableEndDate.Checked = True
Else
    dtTaskEnd.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    dtTaskEnd.CustomFormat = " "
    dtTaskEnd.Value = Date.FromOADate(0)
    dtTaskEnd.Enabled = False
    cbEnableEndDate.Checked = False
End If
```

Comment: Tricksy/hacky but effective. :)

Answer (score 66):

Just set the property as follows:

When the user press "clear button" or "delete key" do

```vb
dtpData.CustomFormat = " "  'An empty SPACE
dtpData.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
```

On `DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged` event do

```vb
dtpData.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree - I suppose because it seemed to be the most appropriate. And I didn't have the reputation qualification to comment.

Comment: It also works to set `dtpData.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short` (or some other format) instead of `dtpData.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`

Comment: What if the datepicker gets opened, the selected date is correct so the user closes it back again?

Comment: The problem described by Ben above is exactly what I ran into. If the value is hidden with a blank `CustomFormat`, the user drops open the calendar, the desired date is already selected and they click it to re-display this in the DateTimePicker, the `ValueChanged` event doesn't fire (as it hasn't actually changed) and so the blank custom format doesn't get removed.

I ended up using the `CloseUp` event instead of `ValueChanged`, which solves this problem, but means that closing the calendar via its button, rather than clicking a date, still re-adds the date into the field. Not ideal...

Answer (score 24):

this worked for me for c#

```
if (enableEndDateCheckBox.Checked == true)
{
    endDateDateTimePicker.Enabled = true;
    endDateDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;                
}
else
{
    endDateDateTimePicker.Enabled = false;
    endDateDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    endDateDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " ";
}
```

nice one guys!

Answer (score 5):

In case anybody has an issue with setting datetimepicker control to blank during the form load event, and then show the current date as needed, here is an example:

MAKE SURE THAT `CustomFormat = "    "` has same number of spaces (at least one space) in both methods

```
Private Sub setDateTimePickerBlank(ByVal dateTimePicker As DateTimePicker)    

    dateTimePicker.Visible = True
    dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "    " 
End Sub


Private Sub dateTimePicker_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
                    System.EventArgs) Handles dateTimePicker.MouseHover

    Dim dateTimePicker As DateTimePicker = CType(sender, DateTimePicker)
    If dateTimePicker.Text = "    " Then
        dateTimePicker.Text = Format(DateTime.Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to edit your formatting a little here.

Comment: @Catherine The standard is for variable names to begin with a lowercase letter. Changing to this improves the formatting, because that's what Stack Overflow expects for .NET.

Answer (score 4):

When I want to display an empty date value I do this

```
            if (sStrDate != "")
            {
                dateCreated.Value = DateTime.Parse(sStrDate);
            }
            else
            {
                dateCreated.CustomFormat = " ";
                dateCreated.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            }
```

Then when the user clicks on the control I have this:

```
            private void dateControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                ((DateTimePicker)sender).Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Long;    
            }
```

This allows you to display and use an empty date value, but still allow the user to be able to change the date to something when they wish.

Keep in mind that sStrDate has already been validated as a valid date string.

Answer (score 4):

The basic concept is the same told by others. But its easier to implement this way when you have multiple dateTimePicker.

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
dateTimePicker1.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Dtp_ValueChanged);
dateTimePicker1.ShowCheckBox=true;
dateTimePicker1.Checked=false;


dateTimePicker2.Value = DateTime.Now;
dateTimePicker2.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Dtp_ValueChanged);
dateTimePicker2.ShowCheckBox=true;
dateTimePicker2.Checked=false;
```

the value changed event function

```
        void Dtp_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTimePicker dtp = (DateTimePicker)sender;
            if (dtp.ShowCheckBox)
            {
                if (dtp.Checked)
                {
                    dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                }
                else
                {
                    dtp.CustomFormat = " ";
                    dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
            }
        }
```

When unchecked
[image]

When checked
[image]

Comment: This is the best solution for the problem.

Comment: This handler here doesn't fire when the underlying datasource populates a null value as technically, the dtp value doesn't change. Therefore this is no good for that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Listen , 
Make Following changes in your code if you want to show empty datetimepicker and get null when no date is selected by user, else save date.

1. Set datetimepicker **FORMAT** property to custom.
2. set **CUSTOM FORMAT** property to empty string " ".
3. set its **TAG** to 0 by default.
4. **Register Event** for datetimepicker VALUECHANGED.

### Now real work starts

if user will interact with datetimepicker its **VALUECHANGED** event will be called and there set its TAG property to 1.

### Final Step

Now when saving, check if its **TAG** is zero, then save NULL date else if **TAG** is 1 then pick and save Datetime picker value.

It Works like a charm.

Now if you want its value be changed back to empty by user interaction, then add checkbox and show text "Clear" with this checkbox.
if user wants to clear date, simply again set its **CUSTOM FORMAT** property to empty string
" ", and set its **TAG** back to 0.
Thats it..

Answer (score 0):

Better to use text box for calling/displaying date and while saving use DateTimePicker.
Make visible property true or false as per requirement.

For eg : During form load make Load date in Textbox and make DTPIcker invisible and while adding vice versa