# How to stop DateTimePicker from showing Todays Date

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

Everytime when I start my program DateTimePicker automatically shows todays date and time. How can I stop this ? How can I make it blank ?

I have a DOB DateTimePicker. For some users I don't know their DOB so I would like the DateTimePicker to show null or empty field.

Comment: This is really two questions in one - setting the value of the DateTimePicker is actually quite easy. Making it blank however is a little trickier. See this previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846395/how-can-i-make-a-datetimepicker-display-an-empty-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to allow it to be blank but you could use the ShowCheckBox and Checked properties set to true.  The DateTimePicker will then have a checkbox in addition to the date dropdown.  The date dropdown is disabled when not checked.  This allows you to have a 'no value' or null for the DOB when the checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 5):

Set `DateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " "` Make sure there is a space. This will show up as a blank space.

I used a `DataRowView drv = DBBindingSource(DB)`. along with a control statement to set null when needed.

```
if(drv.Row["DOB"] == DBNull.Value)
{
  DateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " ";
}
else
{
  DateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this CodeProject article on a [Nullable DateTimePicker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5428/Nullable-DateTimePicker). It inhertis from `DateTimePicker`.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this :**

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.Today
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set it's [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) property to the date you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about  datetimepicker from Trent Richardson, have a look at this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12645192/551811

basically, set the inputbox value in the onClose event.

```
$('input.datetime').datetimepicker({
        onClose: function (value) {
                        $('input.datetime').val(value);
                    }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
Public Sub ClearDatePicker(ByVal DatePicker As DateTimePicker)

DatePicker.CustomFormat = " "

DatePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom

End Sub
```

then the `datetimepicker` will be displayed empty.