# vb.net using sql database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

Im currently doing my thesis which is to build a system. I was trying to save records from textboxes to datagridview. One of them is a date time picker which always has a default value. What I would like to happen is when I would not want to select a date for schedule let's say, when I click on save button, it show on the datagridview an empty value for the said date timpicker.

Please help me! Thaaaanks in advance

Comment: Where is your `tried code`??

Comment: I did not tried anything yet actually coz I dont know what the code actually is for that. Can someone help me and give me like an idea or sample how to do it? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but here you can not ask to `build a whole application` for you .. but the these link might hep you .. http://www.encodedna.com/2013/05/add-new-row-using-gridview.htm

Comment: I mean, the system is running I just don't know how to code that for the value of the datetimepicker to be empty. I'll check the link. Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846395/how-can-i-make-a-datetimepicker-display-an-empty-string