# Date picker doesnt allow edit and no null accepting

Tags: wpf, date, mvvm, infragistics, picker

I am new to .NET 3.5 , WPF, infragistics and MVVM.

I have two calender controls and button control ( when clicking the button user see a list of events between the date range. We follow MVVM pattern

1. Start Date(Date Picker) 2. End date(Date Picker) 3. search button

My bussiness gave me some set of rules through which user will be validated.

I have done all  validation for the date controls   except for the following two:

1. when editing the date picker (manually with out using calender and typing the date) the change event is never recognized in View Model
2. Date picker is not allowing null values ( i need my one my date picker to be empty in page load).

If any body wants i can post my code also..

thanks
Divya

Answer (score 0):

There is an ASP.NET version of the datepicker that allows nullable, found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/DatePickerInASPdotNET.aspx) on CodeProject. There was a similar question posted but it was for WinForms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151652/how-to-set-win-forms-datetime-picker-to-have-no-default-value/2151678#2151678). Ok, the code is for Winforms, maybe you might be able to port it for webforms i.e. asp.net.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Thanks fro your quick answer. My application is also Winforms.it is a infragistics date picker