# Prevent C# date time picker defaulting to todays date on dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a custom DateTimePicker control which allows null values. When the field is null and I select the drop down calendar selector, and click out of the control, todays date will be entered as the default value,

Picture:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXHED.png)

Automatically it will select todays date when I drop the menu down.

Is there a way to prevent the picker from automatically selecting todays date?

Kind regards,

Comment: I have a config parameter of allowNullable so i would like to have it not select anything if that config is set to true

Comment: oops sorry deleted your comment

Comment: what is the date you want to have it by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set win forms datetime picker to have no default value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151652/how-to-set-win-forms-datetime-picker-to-have-no-default-value)