# Set Null value in DateTimePicker in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a `winform` based Desktop application in C#. I would like the user to set the DateTimePicker to `Null`. I am developing a search box, and would like to ignore the date if it is set to `Null`

Here is what I am doing :

```
     this.dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = " ";
     this.dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

     private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         this.dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yy";
     }
```

So far so good. However, once the user selects the date, the `dateTimePicker2` control shows some date ( the date the user has selected). There is no way to set the date to null again. I am not keen to enable the checkbox associated with the `datetimepicker` control.

I was wondering if it is possible to set the `datetimepicker` date to `null`.

Thanks

Comment: No, I dont think this is possible in Winforms.

Comment: Is it allowed in your form to leave the datetimepicker empty?

Comment: Why not have a control next to it `"Clear"`, then set the Custom format again when you say clear or maybe [another datepicker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10155/Yet-another-nullable-DateTimePicker-control)

Comment: Ya, when the `Customformat` is " ", I would be setting the date value to `datemin`. So, I know, if the user has set the date or not.

Comment: @V4Vendetta, Ya, that is what I have been planning, if I am not able to clear the entries manually

Comment: it's possible I will post an example of how to do it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTimePicker Null Value (.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284364/datetimepicker-null-value-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set datetimepicker with null value if date not selected(c# winforms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983563/how-to-set-datetimepicker-with-null-value-if-date-not-selectedc-winforms)

Answer (score 5):

This is in reference from a post that is old but other users on this site have posted it here you go

```
// Use ValueChanged to decide if the value should be displayed:
    dateTimePicker1.ValueChanged += (s, e) => { dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = (dateTimePicker1.Checked && dateTimePicker1.Value != dateTimePicker1.MinDate) ? "MM/dd/yyyy" : " "; };

    //When getting the value back out, use something like the following:
    DateTime? dt = (dateTimePicker1.Checked && dateTimePicker1.Value != dateTimePicker1.MinDate) ?  (DateTime?) dateTimePicker1.Value : null; 
    // or
    DateTime dt2 = (dateTimePicker1.Checked && dateTimePicker1.Value != dateTimePicker1.MinDate) ?  dateTimePicker1.Value : DateTime.MinValue;
```

or you can set the CustomFormat to " " an empty space like the following below

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat= " ";
```

Comment: Would it be possible to set without using the `dateTimePicker1.Checked`. I am not using the checkbox associated with the `datetimepicker`

Comment: that value is just a boolean and you should be able to apply the opposite like so 
`DateTime? dt = (!dateTimePicker1.Checked && dateTimePicker1.Value != dateTimePicker1.MinDate) ?  (DateTime?) dateTimePicker1.Value : null; `

Comment: Kiran check the updated answer as well for The `dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat`

Comment: Hey.. Thank you so much for your time and help. I will check in a moment and let you know

Answer (score 4):

Add `checkbox` to your `datetime` picker property:

```
string datevalue = dateTimePicker2.Checked != true ? "N/A": dateTimePicker2.Text;**
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible because DateTime is not nullable.

But you could use `DateTime.MinValue` this way tou can still compare easily

```
if (datetimepicker.DateTime == DateTime.MinValue)
{
  // just as good as null, maybe
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if it is possible to set the datetimepicker date to null

There's no way to set `DateTimePicker.Value` to `null`, because its type isn't nullable. MSDN says, that:

> If the Value property has not been changed in code or by the user, it
>   is set to the current date and time (DateTime.Now).

But this isn't a problem. You should set to null some bound property, not the `DateTimePicker.Value`:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DateTime? DateTimeFilter
    {
        get { return dateTimeFilter; }
        set
        {
            if (dateTimeFilter != value)
            {
                dateTimeFilter = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DateTimeFilter");
            }
        }
    }
    private DateTime? dateTimeFilter;        

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation is omitted
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly MyModel model;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        model = new MyModel();
        dateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add("Value", model, "DateTimeFilter", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(model.DateTimeFilter.HasValue ? string.Format("User has selected '{0}'.", model.DateTimeFilter) : "User hasn't selected anything.");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here's the data binding magic: our model's property becomes null, 
        // and datetimepicker's value becomes DateTime.Now, as it was initially set
        model.DateTimeFilter = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is not nullable type.
But you can do this trick:
Just add a checkbox on the date picker, you can find it on properties and set **ShowCheckBox** to **True**.
You can use this conditional:

```
if(datePicker.Checked){
    //Do some stuff to ignore the Date Picker value
}
```

For additional info, I'm use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, I'm not check the other IDE yet.
Hope this help. 
 Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when using a DateTimeControl on a SharePoint Application Page.

```
if (dtcOpenDate.SelectedDate != DateTime.Now)
{
    item["Open Date"] = dtcOpenDate.SelectedDate;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation replaces the original Value property with a nullable DateTime which handles the CheckBox state in the setter. The default date can be set flexibly, in my circumstance a start of year date is easier to work with then min value or today. Setting a custom format of " " when null i felt doesn't improve to user experience but feel free to change, I chose to keep it simple.

```
public class DateTimePickerAdvanced : DateTimePicker
{
    public DateTime DefaultDate { get; set; }

    public DateTimePickerAdvanced()
    {
        DefaultDate = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01);
    }

    public new DateTime? Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ShowCheckBox && !this.Checked ? null : (DateTime?)base.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null && !this.ShowCheckBox)
            {
                throw new Exception("ShowCheckBox must be enabled in order to set DateTimePicker to null");
            }

            base.Value = value == null ? DefaultDate : (DateTime)value;

            if (this.ShowCheckBox)
            {
                if (value == null && this.Checked)
                {
                    this.Checked = false;
                }
                else if (value != null && !this.Checked)
                {
                    this.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```