# Nullable dateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I would like the user to set the DateTimePicker to Null when I hide it. I have written a code but it only shows the year portion '00' and shows tomorrow's date. Like "01-Jan-00". I want the whole date-month-year Null.

This is the code I have used:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
```

Comment: There is no simple way to do this with the default DateTimePicker, as you'll find issues with the Custom Format route if you then want to set different dates in the future. It may not work for your solution, but you can set `ShowCheckBox` to true, and then only read the date from the DateTimePicker if the checkbox is checked. It's the simplest way around it, if not the most elegant, unless you NEED the date to be blank.

Comment: Thank you. 
I am using the ShowCheckBox. But the date doesn't get Null completely. If I unchecked the box it stores '01-Jan-00' or the previous checked input's date.

Comment: Do you NEED the date to be null? Does it harm the application if the date is always set to the current date, for example, if you only read the date if the checkbox is ticked? `DateTime? cancelDate = datCancelDate.Checked ? (DateTime?)datCancelDate.Value : null;` is an exert from my project where I did something similar, and my form just shows the current date in the box, but only saves the date if they check the box. Otherwise you have to deal with all the hacky ways to work around it if it HAS to be blank.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be null. Cause I am storing some products name who doesn't have any expire date. That's why I want those products' expire date values to be null.

Comment: If you won't ever have a date for those cases, why not consider hiding the DateTimePicker in those cases? Otherwise, check @Softwarehuset's answer for a few alternatives, or search ways to customise the control to your needs. There is no *simple* way of doing this though, as the DateTimePicker isn't designed to have a blank entry.

Answer (score 0):

there are many answers that could sove your problem

[How can I make a DateTimePicker display an empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846395/how-can-i-make-a-datetimepicker-display-an-empty-string)

or

[Set Null value in DateTimePicker in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723316/set-null-value-in-datetimepicker-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Refer here   [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.showcheckbox%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4)

```
   public void CreateMyDateTimePicker()
{
   // Create a new DateTimePicker control and initialize it.
   DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();

   // Set the MinDate and MaxDate.
   dateTimePicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(1985, 6, 20);
   dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today;

   // Set the CustomFormat string.
   dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd";
   dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

   // Show the CheckBox and display the control as an up-down control.
   dateTimePicker1.ShowCheckBox = true;
   dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
}
```