# How do I initialise DateTimePicker to Null or Empty?

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

How initialize a DateTimePicker to Null or Empty in windows forms?

I tried:

```
dtNascimento.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dtNascimento.CustomFormat = " ";
```

But then does not allow changing the value.

Comment: Why are you setting the *format* to ` `? That seems like a very odd thing to do.

Comment: It was the only way I could do that start empty.

Comment: You could make it nullable like this: `DateTime?` or you can use `DateTime.MinValue` to set it back to a Jan 1 the year 0001: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I try set MinValue, but error: Value of '01/01/0001 00:00:00' is not valid

Comment: A nullable DateTimePicker is Codeproject.com's favorite project.  Many to choose from, you don't need one more.

Comment: I meant to use MinValue instead of the custom format.

Comment: Check if this could be your case

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723316/set-null-value-in-datetimepicker-in-c-sharp

Comment: Set as MinValue or the case from link it work, thanks all. Mainly bkribbs and Dario...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its work

```
dtNascimento.CustomFormat = " ";
dtNascimento.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

 private void dtNascimento_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     dtNascimento.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
 }
```

[Set Null value in DateTimePicker in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723316/set-null-value-in-datetimepicker-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ShowCheckBox=true` and `Checked=false` properties values to indicate that no (valid) date/time is selected. And you can combine it with the custom format on `CheckedChanged` event if you want to really show a blank value when the checkbox is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat easy to extend the DateTimePicker control. Have a look at http://emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2005/01/The-DateTimePicker-control.aspx