# DatePicker 2-way binding not updating when bound value starts as Null

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datepicker

I have a DatePicker control that is bound to a DateTime object:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDocu.StartDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I sometimes initiate `SelectedDocu.StartDate` with data before displaying it via WPF. Other times, it's null and I expect the user to add the date.

*When the* `SelectedDocu.StartDate` *object is already initialized to an actual DateTime object and then updated via the DatePicker, 2-way binding works as expected* (== it updates when the user changes the date, the underlying setter is called and I can follow that flow via breakpoints). (It's the most standard, plain vanilla PropertyChanged setup you can imagine, I won't even post it. )

But when the DateTime object is null and the DatePicker is used to select a date, the setter for the object doesn't even get called. The control displays the newly selected date, but the databinding doesn't update.

I should add that `SelectedDocu.StartDate` is actually of type Object; it's not a typed DateTime instance. I'm not expecting that to be a problem because the unboxing works well everywhere else I'm doing databinding this way, including the picker for instantiated versions of `SelectedDocu.StartDate`.

Any idea what's going on?

### Update

Using Object to store a DateTime does work, and the unboxing works correctly, as well. I did find a way to reproduce this issue where Object<->DateTime binding *doesn't* work, but it's a semi-complicated setup across multiple classes with getters/setters. I'll try to post a reproducible example when I find the time - either in this question or as a new post. For now, I've found ways to work around the issue.

Comment: Consider Converters?

Comment: Maybe? I just realize that object is nullable, while DateTime is not (it's a value object). That might be part of the issue?

Comment: This answer might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983563/how-to-set-datetimepicker-with-null-value-if-date-not-selectedc-winforms It's for Winforms, but along the same lines of "DateTime can't be null, if you want it to be null..." But I don't understand why I can properly 2-way databind a nullable `DateTime?` (just tested it, it works), but not an Object that is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set datetimepicker with null value if date not selected(c# winforms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983563/how-to-set-datetimepicker-with-null-value-if-date-not-selectedc-winforms)

Comment: Binding to an object property works just fine for me. Could you please provide a repo of your issue including the full code of your view model?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what's really going on. I made things (binding a DatePicker to an Object, which is unboxed to a DateTime at runtime) work just fine in a new test project. But it's failing in my specific setup, and I can't figure out how it's functionally different so that I can ask "why is this not working even though that works?"

Comment: can you share a demo to github for us to debug?

Comment: Added an update. I'll try to do this when I find the time.

Answer (score 1):

The selectedDate of DatePicker from WPF uses property

```
public Nullable<DateTime> SelectedDate { get; set; }
```

Please check [MSDN - SelectedDate property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx/) for more details.

Check [C# Nullable Datetime](https://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime) for more detail.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Wait, what? _"Nullable datetime and null object is not the same, because null in nullable datetime is equal to datetime.MinValue."_ - thats simply not true! `datetime.MinValue` is `01.01.0001 0:00:00` - not null...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the INotifyPropertyChanged interface has been implemented on the class where your DateTime property is located. Also make sure that the setter of the property is calling NotifyPropertyChanged() method appropriately. Please see the following link to see how to implement the interface:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

Let me know if this does not help.

Comment: It's definitely implemented correctly. As evidenced by the fact that things work splendidly when the bound object isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this comrade :D

```
    public DateTime DateStarted
    {
        get
        {
            //SET
            if (this.EmployeeJobAssignments == null)
                this.EmployeeJobAssignments = new EmployeeJobAssignments();

            return this.EmployeeJobAssignments.DateStarted;
        }
        set { this.EmployeeJobAssignments.DateStarted = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("DateStarted");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't just put a code. Please explain your solution

Answer (score 0):

> OR try this Hybrid code-behind with MVVM set it on a parameter
>   constructor class

```
private ListBox listBox

public MyClassViewModel(ListBox listBox)
{
    this.listBox = listBox
}

public void MyMethod(){
    DateTime selectedDate = this.listBox.SelectedDate;

}
```