# How to Prevent DataTimePicker Calendar column load with default date

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am using `DateTimePicker` calendar column in windows application and when it loads display the current date as default.. I want to load the calendar cell with empty.. and allow user to select date.. thanks for advance

Comment: do you mean to say datetime picker?

Comment: yes..I am using datetime picker

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947726/set-datetimepicker-value-to-be-null) for default value to be null and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284364/how-to-alter-a-net-datetimepicker-control-to-allow-enter-null-values) for allowing null values to be entered in datetime picker.