# Setting the Date Time Picker to blank or 0 value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, date, datepicker

I have this form right here, where the user will add the start date of the diagnosis. pretty simple right? but in the `end` diagnosis how would I set it to a blank? or 0 value? here's my form.[image]

Comment: Could you show the code?
Hint though would be to use Nullable<DateTime> DateTime? so it can store null.
DateTime is a value object and therefore cannot store null

Comment: In my database, the data type is only date. I mean in the UI how would set their initial values to null or 0? it will have a value if the user clicks it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTimePicker Null Value (.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284364/datetimepicker-null-value-net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do is to set `ShowCheckBox` to true. If the `CheckBox` is not checked, consider that no end date is set.

Comment: end date is set = 0? or null?

Comment: No, the `Value` property is still set to a valid date. You need to test the `Checked` property to decide if you want to use the date or not.

Answer (score 2):

i think, it is not possible to set it as blank or 0 value.. the least you can do is to set it in its MinDate if it's null..

this one works for me..

```
 dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

 dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't want it to be set to 0. It makes no sense (1/1/01 ? most of DB doesn't event store this date)

You should put it either the same as start or in a reasonable margin which describe the common scenario (like + 2 weeks)

Answer (score 0):

Try [setting the Value property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdtd4tst.aspx). However I think there is a limit on how far back you can set the value.

Comment: I want the datetime picker to display blank. or a null value how can I achieve that?

Comment: You cant null the date value you could only set it to a date far in the past. See Thomas Levesque's answer about placing a check box next to the date, that might get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an external checkbox and disable the datetimepicker when you wish to signify no-date.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.Date
```

It would return you only date

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

All solved now just had to adjust. As what you guys were saying i wasn't setting the value or the properties so it would all ways be null anyway

```
private string _BirthDate;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now; // Ensures no future dates are set.
            dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            //dateTimePicker1.Checked = true;
            dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat;
            dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public string BirthDate
        {
            set
            {
                if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Date == DateTime.Today)
                {
                    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";

                }
                else
                {
                    _BirthDate = value;
                }
            }
            get { return _BirthDate; }
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           BirthDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
        }
```