# How to clear a data bound date time picker?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm binding date to a date time picker control like this on windows form.

```
       dtpDOB.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[4]);
```

And when I want to clear it I'm using this code under a button click event.
This is how I do that.

```
      dtpDOB.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dtpDOB.CustomFormat = "";
        dtpDOB.Checked = false;
```

But it does not work.
How to solve this?

Comment: what do u mean by clear ? do you want it to be blank ? or any value which should appear on reset

Comment: @varsha just to not to appear with bound date. Appear as today date as in form load.

Comment: try dateTimePicker.ResetText();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should help you [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846395/how-can-i-make-a-datetimepicker-display-an-empty-string) To display blank in the picker field

and this too [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284364/how-to-alter-a-net-datetimepicker-control-to-allow-enter-null-values)